# Sorting class gender when reading from a file

Tags: c++

Hello I'm new here and I have a small problem, I would be grateful if you helped me

studentTest

```
while (!input.eof()) {
    stud.read(input);
    if (== 'M')
        stud.print();

}
```

Now here where I'm stuck at I can print them all successfully but I don't know about `if ( == 'M')`, I dont know what to put in so I can sort them based on males only any clue on how to fix it ?

I have 2 header files contain classes Student and GradeRecord and both has getters and setters in another c++ files.

this is where the `stud.read(input)` reads from

```
void Student::read(ifstream &file){
char sex;
string line;
double math, computer, english;
string name;

    getline(file, name, ',');
    s.setName(name);

    file >> sex;
    file.ignore();
    s.setSex(sex);

    file >> math;
    file.ignore();
    s.grade.setMathGrade(math);

    file >> computer;
    file.ignore();
    s.grade.setComputerGrade(computer);

    file >> english;
    file.ignore();
    s.grade.setEnglishGrade(english);
```

}

and then it prints it based on this function.

```
void Student::print(){

s.getSex();
double m = s.grade.getMathGrade();
double c = s.grade.getComputerGrade();
double e = s.grade.getEnglishGrade();
double a = s.grade.getAverage();

cout << left << setw(24) << s.getName() << setw(15) << left << letterGrade(m) << setw(15) << left << letterGrade(c) << setw(15) << left << letterGrade(e) << setw(15) << left << s.grade.getTotal() << setw(15) << left << letterGrade(a) << endl;
```

}

EDITED

i dont know how to put the full code so i made it in word doc i would be happy if u downloaded 
[enter link description here](http://www.gulfup.com/?yKVGht)

Comment: Mind, showing us the header file with class student. Aslo please clarify your question more. "I dont know what to put in so I can sort them based on males only any clue on how to fix it" is just too broad for us.

Comment: aslo show us the ifstream file format.

Comment: "I dont know what to put in so I can sort them based on males only any clue on how to fix it" is answered with if((stud.getSex() == "male") |  (stud.getSex() == "M"))

Comment: create a getSex() function that gets sex from object s and returns it.

Comment: @Bot : if `stud.getSex()` was a char*, `stud.getSex() == "male"` would be a **very** bad advice !

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that sex was char I assumed it was string. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Bot i tried it but it didnt work i edited my post and put the word doc file full code in it so i would be glad if u checked it

Comment: why did you initialize sex in read function it is already intialized in the class? You are just putting your sex in another variable.

Comment: @Bot XD omg i just realized that ahh i made it much more complicated thanks XD how do i close this case though?

Comment: great, well bye then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `getSex` just returns an M or an F as a char, `if (stud.getSex() == 'M')` should be sufficient.  As an aside, I did not believe that I would ever see the call `stud.getSex()`, let alone in such a completely innocent context.

Comment: yea i did that too before asking but it doesn't return any values

Answer (score 0):

Correct function

```
while (!input.eof()) 
{
    stud.read(input);
    if ((stud.getSex() == 'M') | (stud.getSex() == "m"))
    {
        stud.print();
    }

}
```

This should check your object's sex and return it as string to be checked.

Comment: While `|` will technically work, I'd assume you meant to use `||` rather than `|`.

Comment: They both work, but I suppose || is better suited because it is logical or rather than bitwise or.

Comment: i tried it but it didnt work i edited my post and put the word doc file full code in it so i would be glad if u checked it